# ASP.NET error "Could not connect to SQL Server"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have an application deployed in separate website on dedicated port (path: https://server:8085/service). It works.
Now I want to deploy it under new IIS application (path https://server/newapp/service). The problem is that I'm getting error that the app is unable to connect to sql server. The app pool is the same and both the site and the application point to the same folder on disk.

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unable to find the specified file]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +642
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan retryInterval) +309

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session database.]
   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection conn, Exception e) +3539419
   System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan retryInterval) +3533255
   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id, Boolean& usePooling) +500
   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ResetItemTimeout(HttpContext context, String id) +78
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +707
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12335126
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: please you can share connectionstring code format and let me know where you place  this piece of code whether  in web.cofig or some where else

Comment: Nazir, it's standard connection string in web.config. What is weird that the application works fine from dedicated site/port and there is no problem with connnecting to the database from there.

Comment: is it using a relative path for anything?

Comment: no, it does not use any relative paths

Answer (score 1):

Please check the configuration file and you should also check for **access privileges** for the application and sqlserver.

Comment: The configuration file is fine - it works for dedicated site. What kind of access privileges do you mean?

Comment: the application which you are hosted in IIS does't have full control..check for security.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop and 'create new document' then change the .txt extension to .udl, then you can enter the SQL server credentials and 'Test Connection'

my bet is the SQL server is not accessible have you

'Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.'

Comment: it is accessible from the same application in dedicated site on IIS